# Data merge on-the-fly with natural balanced merge sort

Tags: java, sorting

I have implemented (external) natural balanced two-way merge sort for sorting text files (text files contain strings separated by new line character). The algorithm works as expected but there is part of it that I would like to improve. First, the algorithm is separated into two parts: first part distributes the input data, the second part merges it. The first part of the algorithm works good but the second part is not implemented in the right way. The problem here is that the length of next runs is read in advance from both temp files with the help of `getNextStringRunLength` function.

For example:

```
int n = getNextStringRunLength(temp_file_1)
int m = getNextStringRunLength(temp_file_2)
```

The algorithm merges data until (n+m) values are merged into a new run of a length (n+m). The idea here is to merge data on the fly without reading runs lengths before that. The main question here is how to implement merge procedure on the fly?

**Sample of the input.txt**
Car
Motor
Bike
Book
John
Carl

**Sample of the output.txt**
Bike
Book
Car
Carl
John
Motor

Please see code below and thanks for the answers!

```
/**
* Sorts input text file of strings using natural merge procedure with a help of two auxiliary files.
* In the first part it uses these files to distribute input data and then merges them in the second part.
* Input data is distributed using <i>writeNextStringRun</i> method which writes next string run
* to auxiliary file. When it merges runs to a length of (m+n) it uses function<i>getNextStringRunLength</i>
* which returns length of a next string run found in auxiliary files and thus helping to merge run of length m 
* and run of length n into a single run of length (m+n).
* <p>
* Distribute and merge procedure repeat until all the data is sorted in ascending order. The algorithm
* produces a brand new output file which contains sorted data and thus retains input file unchanged.
* Since the algorithm is balanced it changes the role of input/output files after merge part ends. At the
* end of algorithm all empty auxiliary files are deleted from the local file system, the auxiliary file which
* contains sorted data becomes output file of the algorithm.
* <p>
* @param temp_files         number of auxiliary files used for data distribution and merging.
* @param working_dir        path to local directory where all the sorting takes place.
* @param main_string_file   local text file which contains all input data separated by new a line character.
* @throws IOException       if an input or output exception occurred during file operations.
*/

public static void naturalBalancedTwoWayMergeSortStrings(int temp_files, String working_dir, File main_string_file) throws IOException
{
    long data_read = 0;     
    String last_string_runs = new String[temp_files];

    int i,j;
    int n,m;
    int rw_switch = 0;
    int run_counter = 0;
    String line_1 = null;
    String line_2 = null;
    int file_write_pointer;
    long output_file_length = 0;
    String file_extension = ".txt";

    File input_files[] = new File[temp_files];
    File output_files[] = new File[temp_files];
    String input_file_name = "input_string_file_";
    String output_file_name = "output_string_file_";
    File sorted_file = new File(working_dir + "/main_string_sorted" + file_extension);

    BufferedWriter input_file_writers[] = new BufferedWriter[temp_files];
    BufferedReader input_file_readers[] = new BufferedReader[temp_files];
    BufferedReader run_length_readers[] = new BufferedReader[temp_files];
    BufferedWriter output_file_writers[] = new BufferedWriter[temp_files];
    BufferedReader main_file_reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(main_string_file));

    for(int p=0; p<temp_files; p++)
    {
        input_files[p] = new File(working_dir + input_file_name + (p+1) + file_extension);
        output_files[p] = new File(working_dir + output_file_name + (p+1) + file_extension);
        input_file_writers[p] = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(input_files[p],true));
        run_length_readers[p] = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input_files[p]));
    }

    /* START - initial run distribution */
    long main_file_length = main_string_file.length();

    while(data_read < main_file_length)
    {
        writeNextStringRun(main_file_reader,input_file_writers[run_counter%2]);
        run_counter++;
    }

    main_file_reader.close();
    input_file_writers[0].close();
    input_file_writers[1].close();
    /* END - initial run distribution. */

    /* START - merge all runs. */
    do
    {
        for(int r=0; r<temp_files; r++)
        {
            input_file_readers[r] = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input_files[r]));
            run_length_readers[r] = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input_files[r]));
            output_file_writers[r] = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(output_files[r],true));              
        }

        /* >>> This is not the righ approach <<< */
        n = getNextStringRunLength(run_length_readers[0],0);
        m = getNextStringRunLength(run_length_readers[1],1);            

        try
        {
            line_1 = input_file_readers[0].readLine();              
        }
        catch(Exception e){}

        try
        {
            line_2 = input_file_readers[1].readLine();              
        }
        catch(Exception e){}

        file_write_pointer = 0;

        while(n > 0 || m > 0)
        {
            i = 1;
            j = 1;

            while((line_1 != null && i <= n) && (line_2 != null && j <= m))
            {                   
                if(line_1.compareTo(line_2) < 0)
                {
                    output_file_writers[file_write_pointer%2].write(line_1 + "\n");                     

                    try
                    {
                        line_1 = input_file_readers[0].readLine();                          
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){}

                    i++;
                }

                else
                {
                    output_file_writers[file_write_pointer%2].write(line_2 + "\n");                     

                    try
                    {
                        line_2 = input_file_readers[1].readLine();                                      
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){}

                    j++;                        
                }
            }

            while(line_1 != null && i <= n)
            {
                output_file_writers[file_write_pointer%2].write(line_1 + "\n");                                     

                try
                {
                    line_1 = input_file_readers[0].readLine();                                  
                }
                catch(Exception e){}

                i++;
            }

            while(line_2 != null && j <= m)
            {
                output_file_writers[file_write_pointer%2].write(line_2 + "\n");                 

                try
                {
                    line_2 = input_file_readers[1].readLine();                      
                }
                catch(Exception e){}

                j++;
            }

            file_write_pointer++;

            /* >>> This is not the righ approach <<< */
            n = getNextStringRunLength(run_length_readers[0],0);
            m = getNextStringRunLength(run_length_readers[1],1);                
        }
        /* END - merge all runs. */

        for(int k=0; k<temp_files; k++)
        {
            input_file_readers[k].close();
            run_length_readers[k].close();
            output_file_writers[k].close();
        }

        /* START - swap io files. */
        File temp_store[] = new File[temp_files];

        switch(rw_switch % 2)
        {
            case 0:
            output_file_length = output_files[0].length();
            for(int k=0; k<temp_files; k++)
            {
                input_file_writers[k] = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(input_files[k]));
                temp_store[k] = input_files[k];
                input_files[k] = output_files[k];
                output_files[k] = temp_store[k];
            }
            break;

            case 1:
            output_file_length = output_files[0].length();
            for(int k=0; k<temp_files; k++)
            {
                temp_store[k] = output_files[k];
                output_files[k] = input_files[k];
                input_files[k] = temp_store[k];
                output_file_writers[k] = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(output_files[k]));
            }
            break;
        }
        /* END - swap io files. */

        rw_switch++;
    }
    while(main_file_length > output_file_length);
    /* END - merge all runs. */             
}   

/**
* Writes next string run to auxiliary file.
*
* @param  input_file_reader a reader which reads strings from input text file.
* @param  input_writer      a writer which writes next string run to a auxiliary file.
* @throws IOException       if an input or output exception occurred during file operations.
*/
private static void writeNextStringRun(BufferedReader input_file_reader, BufferedWriter input_writer) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        if(last_string_run != null)
        {
            input_writer.write(last_string_run + "\n");             
            last_string_run = null;
        }

        String min_value = "";
        String current_line = input_file_reader.readLine();         

        while(current_line !=  null)
           {                
            if(current_line.compareTo(min_value) >= 0)
            {
                input_writer.write(current_line + "\n");                    

                data_read += current_line.length() + 1;
                min_value = current_line;

                current_line = input_file_reader.readLine();                
            }

            else
            {
                last_string_run = current_line;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}

/**
* Returns length of next string run in auxiliary string file.
*
* @param  input_file_reader a reader which reads strings from auxiliary input file.
* @param  input_file_index  an index of auxiliary file from which it reads next string run length.
*         This parameter is used in <i>last_string_runs</i> array which contains last runs read from
*         a file with this parameter (index).
* @return next string run length found in auxiliary string file.
* @throws IOException if an input or output exception occurred during file operations.
*/

private static int getNextStringRunLength(BufferedReader input_file_reader, int input_file_index) throws IOException
{
    int run_length = 0;

    try
    {
        if(last_string_runs[input_file_index] != null)
        {
            run_length++;               
        }

        String min_value = "";
        String current_line = input_file_reader.readLine();         

        if(run_length > 0)
        {
            min_value = last_string_runs[input_file_index];
        }

        while(current_line !=  null)
           {                
            if(current_line.compareTo(min_value) >= 0)
            {
                run_length++;
                min_value = current_line;
                current_line = input_file_reader.readLine();                                    
            }

            else
            {
                last_string_runs[input_file_index] = current_line;
                return run_length;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){}

    last_string_runs[input_file_index] = null;

    return run_length;
}
```

Comment: Please, provide the sample inputs and expected outputs. Use unit testing. Learn how to debug. Don't overuse `static` methods (seriously, this is not OOP).

Comment: Do not post it to the comment (nobody would care searching for it) but update the question.

Comment: @Nikolas I haved added examples to the question. Thanks for the tip!!

Comment: If stability is not required, you can use out of order strings as an indicator for run boundaries (end of one run, start of another). This is unstable because two (or more) runs can end up appearing as a single run.

Comment: @Nikolas with this algorithm the stability is not so important. I just want to merge data with no extra file interactions, this slows down the algorithm. Can you please provide some pseudo-code for your suggestion?

Comment: Any more suggestions on this one?